# create mysql subquery with joins where count equals zero

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get results where CountId equals zero. I tired the code below but does not work.Can someone please please help :)

```
SELECT table1.id,table1.name2,table1.name3,table1.name4,table1.name, COUNT(table2.id ) AS CountId
from table1 
LEFT JOIN table2
ON  table1.name4 = table2.name4
AND table1.name3 = table2.name3
AND table1.name2 = table2.name2
WHERE CountId = 0
```

Comment: Pls note the two tables are very large with around 86k records

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an aggregate function (such as `SUM`,`COUNT`,etc) in `WHERE` clause.

Use `HAVING` clause after `GROUP BY`. Also it is a good practice to use alias names when you join multiple tables.

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.name2,t1.name3,t1.name4,t1.name, COUNT(t2.id) AS CountId
from table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON  t1.name4 = t2.name4
                    AND t1.name3 = t2.name3
                    AND t1.name2 = t2.name2
GROUP BY t1.id,t1.name2,t1.name3,t1.name4,t1.name
HAVING COUNT(t2.id) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However it does not give results, probably cause the table is too big. The query runs for a while and then gives the error:  Error in Processing Request
Error code: 503
Error text: Service Unavailable

Comment: @SantoshPillai: If the table is not properly designed try to normalise the data.